# Is there an API that tells me whether a folder is synced or not?

Tags: box-api

I'm trying to write a scirpt to sync Box folders programmatically, and I need to know first whether the folder is synced or not.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out if Box considers the folder synced, or are you trying to build your own sync mechanism?   Box has its own sync client that is now available to all users.

Comment: It's former. Just want to know if the folder is synced in Box or not.

Answer (score 0):

When getting a folder's information, you can request the `sync_state` parameter, which is not returned by default. Possible values for `sync_state` are `synced`, `not_synced`, and `partially_synced`. Files inherit the sync state of their parent folder.

Folder info: `GET https://api.box.com/folders/12345?fields=sync_state`

These parameters are listed in the Box V2 API documentation:

http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-folder-object